# Boy defeats robot zombie in his orphanage's flooded basement, taken to a world of heroes

Tags: story-identification

Read a book in the past that started off with a kid going to the bottom of his school to see a robotic zombie coming out the water.

Kid ends up going to another world where heroes live. There was water because the basement was flooded. The kid ends up going to another world where heroes live. The heros of the other world lived in a city and fought a war against the robotic zombies and he is there to train.

One key thing about the city I remember was a statue of the strongest hero in the war

Comment: This is very brief, can you remember anything else at all about this that you could [edit] in? Any of the overall plot?

Comment: Have a look at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question for some tips on things you could mention that might help someone find the story for you.

Comment: And why was there water at the bottom of his school? Flooded basement? Portal? School on a cliff-face beside an ocean? What sort of heroes? Fantasy? Superheroes? Rescue workers?

Comment: What about the statue of the greatest hero? Are you just saying one existed? Or was there a salient detail you meant to include?

Comment: I think I found it. If the answer is correct, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

[*The Accidental Hero*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11242368-the-accidental-hero) by Matt Myklusch.

> All Jack Blank knows is his bleak, dreary life at St. Barnaby’s Home for the Hopeless, Abandoned, Forgotten, and Lost, an orphanage that sinks further into the swampland of New Jersey with each passing year. His aptitude tests predict that he will spend a long, unhappy career as a toilet brush cleaner. His only chance at escape comes through the comic books donated years ago to the orphanage that he secretly reads in the dark corners of the library.
>
> Everything changes one icy gray morning when Jack receives two visitors that alter his life forever. The first is a deadly robot straight out of one of his comic books that tries its best to blow him up. The second is an emissary from a secret country called the Imagine Nation, an astonishing place where all the fantastic and unbelievable things in our world originate — including Jack. Jack soon discovers that he has an amazing ability — one that could make him the savior of the Imagine Nation and the world beyond, or the biggest threat they've ever faced.

The statue that you're referencing is probably [Legend's Statue](https://imaginenation.fandom.com/wiki/Legend%27s_Statue).

> Legend's Statue, or the Statue of Legend, is a monument built in honor of the fallen hero, Legend, as well as other heroes and even villains that lost their lives in the Battle of Empire City in the first invasion.

The creature he initially fights (and the main enemy of the series), are the [The Rüstov](https://imaginenation.fandom.com/wiki/The_R%C3%BCstov).

> The Rüstov are a parasitic alien force coming from their world, Rüst. They were some of the strongest forces out in the galaxy, seeing Earth as their next target.

....

> When in a host, their host would show a black mark around their right eye, parts of their body becoming mechanical. With time, the host would worsen until everything organic was machinery. There's an exception with the Magus and the Rüstov prince.

Since Jack's power is to communicate with, and control, machines, he's in a unique position to fight the Rüstov, although his ability does also lead to suspicion throughout the series that he might be a spy or traitor for the Rüstov.

Found with a search for `boy enters world through flooded basement and fights robot zombies`